# Network disconnects repeatedly

Tags: debian, wifi

running newest debian/gnome versions on matebook x pro. My home network disconnects periodically, but this does not happen with any other network. I've forgotten the connection and reconnected but this did not help.

Tried to go through several of the solutions online but cannot find a suitable one. One lead is possibly my wifi card not working well with the firmware? (moderate level of experience but definitely not a pro user)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to add additional information. What can you find in the syslog when the issue occurs? What wifi card are you using? Which driver? Which router? 802.11a,b,g,n or ac?